# Left outer join on more than 2 relations at a time in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to perform a left outer join for more that 2 relations in a single statement in pig. Is it possible?

Regards
Harish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, multi-way joins in one step only work for inner joins. Taken from [the official documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/basic.html#join-outer):

> ***Usage***
>
> ...
>
> Outer joins will only work for two-way joins; to perform a multi-way outer join, you will need to perform multiple two-way outer join statements.

So until they add the possibility, which won't be anytime soon (there are no open JIRAs working on it), you will need to do it in 2 statements:

```
A = LOAD 'a' AS (a:chararray,b:int);
B = LOAD 'b' AS (a:chararray,b:chararray);
C = LOAD 'c' AS (a:chararray,b:chararray);
D = JOIN A by $0 LEFT OUTER, B BY $0;
E = JOIN D by $0 LEFT OUTER; C BY $0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.